# How can I set the icon for my program? I mean, the actual .exe that will be on the desktop

Tags: c#, resources, icons

I can change the icon in the WindowsForm.

How can I actually change the icon in the desktop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click the project then click properties.  You can set the icon using the dropdown on the bottom half of the Application page.

Answer (score 1):

You do that by changing the icon in the property settings of the winform project that builds the exe.